# Reset Uniform Type Identifiers on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, quicklook, uti

A colleague of mine has developed a Mac OS X application that creates files with a relatively common file extension in my research field (.fits, an official image format for professional astronomical data). The problem is that these files have nothing to do with the official FITS format, and his application declares a uniform type identifier (UTI) associated with his .fits extension!

Now the metadata of official FITS files, obtained with the `mdls` command, associate his UTI to these files, which screws up some other tools that I have that normally support official FITS files (a quicklook plugin, a viewing application). I erased his application, but the metadata still list his UTI for official FITS files...

Is there any way to reset the UTIs that are "known" on my system? Or the association between UTIs and applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, but try `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -seed`

Comment: I did change something. At least now the metadata of FITS file don't mention the UTI from my colleague's application.

Comment: Look at the other options to seed the LS database with the app declaring the correct UTI.